# Flash Action Script 3 rotate button

Tags: actionscript-3, button, rotation

Could anyone tell me whats wrong with this code? I'm attempting to rotate a button in action script 3 and i keep getting the error:

> ArgumentError: Error #2025: The supplied DisplayObject must be a child
>   of the caller.    at flash.display::DisplayObjectContainer/removeChild()
>     at
>   distributor_app_fla::MainTimeline/NewChartOptionsReturn()[distributor_app_fla.MainTimeline::frame1:218]
>     at
>   distributor_app_fla::MainTimeline/ClickNewChartOptions()[distributor_app_fla.MainTimeline::frame1:101]

I've already Googled the error and everything i read told me to remove the child then re-add it to the frame but it continues to break at the same spot.

code:

```
//defined

var btnNewChartOptions:NewChartOptions = new NewChartOptions();

btnNewChartOptions.y = 279;

btnNewChartOptions.x = 439;

//created

function NewChartDown():String

{

btnNewChartOptions.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, ClickNewChartOptions);

    btnNewChartOptions.alpha = 0;

addChild(btnNewChartOptions);

var NewChartOptionsTween:Tween = new Tween(btnNewChartOptions, "alpha", Strong.easeOut, 0, 1, 1, true);

return "NewChartSelected";

}

//actual code on button

function NewChartOptionsDown():String

{
rightGrayOut.alpha = 0;

addChild(rightGrayOut);

var grayOutTween:Tween = new Tween(rightGrayOut, "alpha", Strong.easeOut, 0, 1, 1, true);

var rotateTween:Tween = new Tween(btnNewChartOptions, "rotation", Strong.easeOut, 0, 180, 1, true);



return "NewChartOptions";

}
```

any help is appreciated!

Comment: To fix your fix try replacing ` removeChild(btnNewChartOptions);` with `if(btnNewChartOptions.parent == this) removeChild(btnNewChartOptions);`. However I think your fix is the wrong approach to begin with.

Comment: @Taurayinope still the same runtime error. and as to putting it into the wrong place thats very possible as im almost completely new to as3. im attempting to make the button rotate with a tween when clicked on

Comment: where else could i put it? if youd like i can copy the complete code but it looks like a mess in a comment

Comment: Just edit your question and post it at the bottom instead of putting it in a comment.

Comment: right above this comment area is a link "edit" click it.

Comment: alright thanks hopefully thats more helpful

Answer (score 0):

There will be no need to remove and re-add the object because it is either present and available to the method or not, meaning if it were available to the method for removal then it would also be available for addressing and manipulation. This sounds a whole lot like a scope/visibility issue.

This code is on frame 1 on the timeline, which means that it should be able to address anything that's directly on the stage or assigned to a variable that is in the same scope at the time the function is run. (In the _root scope if this was AS2, like the methods on frame 1)

Is btnNewChartOptions inside another DisplayObject, like a sprite you use to hold all your buttons or something, as opposed to sitting directly on the stage? Maybe you can describe the object heirarchy you are trying to address as well as how the button gets attached to the stage (e.g. instantiated and attached at runtime or placed on the stage in a keyframe).

Can you provide the error that was being thrown before the add and remove fix was attempted?

Comment: the error was the exact same and as for the objects they're all programatically added on start up. what i think the issue is is that the button isn't added until a different button is clicked. everything else iv attempted to tween in the exact same way has worked fine

Comment: function ClickNewChartOptions(event:MouseEvent):void
{
 if(currentPosition == "NewChartOptions")
  currentPosition = NewChartOptionsDown();
 else
  currentPosition = NewChartOptionsReturn();
}

Comment: Can you paste the code that instantiates the button you're trying to address?

Comment: As well as the code that registers the ClickNewChartOptions handler with whatever it is attached to.

Comment: function NewChartDown():String
{
 btnNewChartOptions.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, ClickNewChartOptions);
 
 btnNewChartOptions.alpha = 0;
 addChild(btnNewChartOptions);
 var NewChartOptionsTween:Tween = new Tween(btnNewChartOptions, "alpha", Strong.easeOut, 0, 1, 1, true);


 return "NewChartSelected";
}

Answer (score 0):

If looks like to me the object has not been added yet to the display list.

```
// replace the following lines
removeChild(btnNewChartOptions);
addChild(btnNewChartOptions);

// with 
if( !this.contains( btnNewChartOptions ) ){
  return "";
}
```

[EDIT]
Your code.

```
//var created
  var btnNewChartOptions:NewChartOptions = new NewChartOptions();
  btnNewChartOptions.y = 279;
  btnNewChartOptions.x = 439;
//button code clicked that creates button
  function NewChartDown():String {
    btnNewChartOptions.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, ClickNewChartOptions);
    btnNewChartOptions.alpha = 0;
    addChild(btnNewChartOptions);
    var NewChartOptionsTween:Tween = new Tween(btnNewChartOptions, "alpha", Strong.easeOut, 0, 1, 1, true);
    return "NewChartSelected";
  }




//function for button
  function NewChartOptionsDown():String {
    rightGrayOut.alpha = 0;
    addChild(rightGrayOut);
    var grayOutTween:Tween = new Tween(rightGrayOut, "alpha", Strong.easeOut, 0, 1, 1, true);
    var rotateTween:Tween = new Tween(btnNewChartOptions, "rotation", Strong.easeOut, 0, 180, 1, true);
    return "NewChartOptions";
  }
```

In your code you provided you are only doing `addChild(btnNewChartOptions);` in the `NewChartDown` function.

So that tells me that `NewChartOptionsDown` can not be called until `NewChartDown` has been called first. Because the btnNewChartOptions has never been added.

What you can do is move `addChild(btnNewChartOptions);` outside of the function.

```
//var created
  var btnNewChartOptions:NewChartOptions = new NewChartOptions();
  btnNewChartOptions.y = 279;
  btnNewChartOptions.x = 439;
  addChild(btnNewChartOptions);
```

Comment: i'm pretty sure its added to the display list because when i run the app the button shows up but gives the error when clicked on

Comment: Well your error states otherwise. Please just try the code supplied. Or post more code relating to the issue.

Comment: i did try it gave the same error. and which part of the code are you wanting? i posted the code where the button if created above and the only other place where that button is mentioned is when its defined

Comment: unfortunately it didnt work.it still threw the same error when i added it outside the function where it was called

Comment: Oh wait a second you have code on the button and on stage? Take the code off the button and move it to stage. The way you are doing it is out of scope and it will never exist on the button.

Comment: Place all code on the main timeline on its own separate layer. In AS2 placing code on the buttons themselves was ok in AS3 you run into scoping issues and is not good practice.

Comment: its all on one frame everything is added and changed dynamically through actionscript, so it should be there. I dont think flash lets you put code directly on objects. what do you meen put it on it's own layer though? like make another actionscript layer with only the code for that button?

Comment: Yes, And what IDE are you using?